# Sandboxed application's communication to kernel extension

Tags: macos, sockets, sandbox, appstore-sandbox, kernel-extension

I want to know if a sandboxed application on MAC like Outlook 2016 or similar can use kernel socket to communicate to kernel extension. Does sandboxed application apply restriction on communication to kernel extensions ?

Thanks,

Comment: I  think what you want to know is if a KEXT can communicate to another userland process using KEXT sockets, when invoked from inside a Sandboxed application with no Network permissions. What I understand till now with my little experience with MAC systems is that a KEXT called in context of Sandboxed application with no Network Access permissions would not be able to communicate with another userland process over KEXT sockets.

Comment: That said, I would also like to know if there is any fast mechanism for userclient to communicate with a user application without using kernel sockets, that is not blocked in sandboxes..